# How to get one->many relationship with a foreign key in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2. My Database is set up as:

```
social_logins
ID |   social_id  | provider
-----------------------------
 1 |      x      | twitter  
 2 |      y      | facebook
 3 |      z      | twitter

twitter_data
ID |   social_id  | some_value
-------------------------------
 1 |      x      | 100
 2 |      y      | 200
 3 |      z      | 100
```

My relationship for the social_logins model is set up as:

```
 public function twitterData()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TwitterData', 'social_id');
    }
```

I want to retrieve back the all the twitter data with the foreign key of social_id in the table. So far I've tried:

```
$socialLogin = Social::find($id);
dd($socialLogin->twitterCounts);
```

but when I try this I just get an empty collection

```
Collection {#346 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

How do I retrieve the one to many relationship with the foreign key in laravel 5.2?

Please note when I do this manually with something like this:

```
TwitterData::where('social_id', $socialLogin->social_id)->get();
```

It returns back all the data correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add local key to your relation method:

```
public function twitterData()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TwitterData', 'social_id','social_id');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Did not realise you had to do that.